# Fusion Orion Drive

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, spaceships

Orion drives are awesome.

Nobody can deny that.  They are however a little outdated and still use pure fission pulse units.  Obviously they are in need of an upgrade!  A good place to start would be to upgrade the pulse units to fission catalyzed fusion device.  Right?  Well, according to a section in [this](https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2016/06/the-nuclear-spear-casaba-howitzer.html?m=0) blog,  it is not such a good idea.

Then I came across this [drive here.](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/surfaceorbit.php#id--Thermonuclear_Orion)  Now, while it is used for Surface to Orbit missions, it may be possible to use it for space.  But how would it perform compared to classical Orion Drives?  What are the potential Pros and cons of a system in space?  And what does it look like exactly?

Comment: That drive includes the requirement of  **"uses fusion explosions, triggered by convergent shock waves from chemical high explosives"** ... This makes generating a viable hard-science answer difficult, as the current Earth supply of Unobtanium and Handwavium has historically been insufficient to create such a thing. The 4 to 6 magnitudes of energy density requirement between chemical explosions and thermonuclear ignition is a very real obstacle.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia page on Project Orion you'd have found this quote *"It proposed the use of a shaped-charge fusion-boosted fission explosive."*  In other words, been there, done that.  Version of Projecvt Orion have been proposed using "fuels" as exotic as ani-matter (which practically is unobtainium).

Comment: Note that there's more antimatter in the world than there is magical x-ray emitting super-explosives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is awkward to provide much in the way of references for any answer here, as the proposed system only seems to exist in the original paper: [Thermonuclear Operation Space Lift](https://vixra.org/pdf/1310.0225v1.pdf). For what its worth, the author [Friedwardt Winterberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedwardt_Winterberg) has had a *lot* to say on the subject of nuclear rocketry over the years an so there's a reasonable chance he knows what he's talking about when it comes to nukes.

Unfortunately the critical component of this system is a hypothetical "super explosive" which is detonated when already under extreme pressure and generates keV-level x-rays. This sounds a little bit like [ballotechnic materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballotechnics)... and indeed, follows the classic description of "[red mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_mercury#Red_mercury_as_a_ballotechnic)" as a wonder material that could directly ignite fusion reactions without the need for a fission primary.

A full debunking of red mercury is outside of the scope of this answer, and I'm probably not the best person to do it anyway. Suffice to say that if these "super explosives" existed they'd be phenomenally useful, but it isn't clear that they are even *possible* to create. Winterberg's paper at least has some theories on how a chemical reaction *might* generate high-energy photons, but the materials remain firmly in the territory of [unobtanium](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/unobtanium.php).

---

With that out of the way, lets concentrate on your specific questions:

> But how would it perform compared to classical Orion Drives?

Within an atmosphere, similarly. It kinda has to, in that it needs to be a high-Isp, high-thrust rocket capable of lifting heavy payloads into orbit in a single stage. The quoted performance figures are very much within the [same ballpark as Orion](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2010/ph240/stetler2/).

> What are the potential Pros and cons of a system in space?

From the paper,

> As shown in Fig. 4, the deuterium-tritium (DT) fusion explosive positioned in the center
> is surrounded by a cm-size spherical shell made up of a super-explosive, surrounded by a metersize sphere of liquid hydrogen. The surface of the hydrogen sphere is covered with many high
> explosive lenses

Lets compare this to a [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)#Vehicle_architecture) pulse unit. Quoting Wikipedia,

> The whole unit was built into a can with a diameter no larger than 6 inches (150 mm) and weighed just over 300 pounds (140 kg)

The Winterberg devices are much larger, require large amounts of liquid hydrogen and not-obviously-practical "super explosives", as opposed to a modified nuclear explosive in a compact and easily storable and manipulable package that was deemed possible to manufacture by 1960's technology.

Liquid hydrogen is an [awkward material](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/liquid-hydrogen) that requires cryogenic storage systems (it liquifies at [~20K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen)) has some storage issues (like [hydrogen embrittlement)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_embrittlement) and ultimately [it is a challenging material for long term storage in microgravity](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20120011680/downloads/20120011680.pdf). There's a lot not to like about it.

The Winterberg rocket is substantially more technologically complex than the Orion rocket, too, requiring a magnetic pusher plate rather than a dumb solid one mounted on pistons.

Given that the performance of the two systems is comparable, there's no obvious benefit to using a Winterberg rocket over an Orion design when in space, and given the relative simplicity of the Orion propulsion units there are arguments that the Winterberg rocket is *less* useful out there. The main benefit of a pure-fusion rocket is that it does not produce radioactive fallout, and so can be operated in an atmosphere without long term environmental risks.

> And what does it look like exactly?

The paper doesn't say. It does say that it has a thick, dimpled pusher plate, rather than the flat pusher plate of the classic Orion design. No other details are gone into. Given the claimed performance of the rocket, the design of the rest of the vehicle would almost certainly look like a Project Orion ship of comparable diameter, given that both rockets would need to absorb powerful blasts and deal with intense x-ray and neutron radiation from the nuclear explosions.

Winterberg speaks of a 10m diameter pusher plate. As luck would have it, NASA examined the possibility of a 10m diameter Orion prototype. There's a veryy poor quality scan of a General Dynamics report containing some diagrams: [Nuclear Pulse Vehicle Study Condensed Summary Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760065935/downloads/19760065935.pdf)... there's another document [Nuclear Pulse Space Vehicle Study Vol IV – Conceptual Vehicle Designs and Operational Systems](http://Nuclear%20Pulse%20Space%20Vehicle%20Study%20Vol%20IV%20%E2%80%93%20Conceptual%20Vehicle%20Designs%20and%20Operational%20Systems,) but NASA's sysadmins have broken something rendering the document currently inaccessible to me. Wikipedia took this image from that document:

[image: NASA 10m project orion prototype]

The Winterberg rocket would have a dimpled pusher plate, and also some additional source of electricity to power the electromagnets used to deflect the plasma from the nuclear explosions, but no details of that can be found in the original paper so it is anybody's guess what that would look like.